# Choosing PostGIS or SQL Server 2008

Tags: postgis, sql-server, software-recommendations

I've been using MS SQL for years. Starting now to develop GIS application and it is required to do queries and store vectors created in OpenLayers in DB.
Assuming I'm developing over .Net, will the most convenient way to use a DB in GIS app be MS SQL 2008 or PostGIS?

I'm using the express edition of 2008 and will be using open source WMS , probably MS4W (or GeoServer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already got experience with SQL Server then the easiest route to get into GIS would be to stick with what you know as the learning curve will be smaller. However, this assumes the SQL Express license will cover your needs in the future, or you can afford the cost of SQL Server licenses.

If you've got the freedom to choose the technology then, without any more specific requirements at this stage, both options should do the job for you. So choose whichever one you want to learn more about. A lot of what you learn about one platform should be transferable to the other.

I don't think the fact you're using .net should make much difference to what database you're connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that if you want to use open source stack preferred choice is PostGIS. There are some support for MS SQL ,but it's not anywhere close to PostGIS. Add all functionality that PostGIS brings, like reprojection it a winner.

I lose my nerves everytime when i have to export data from databse to another app to do basic things like reprojection, but i have more experience from PostGIs than spatial MSSQL.

This counts only database backend and programs like geoserver etc, i have not yet done any real development on C# . net and PostGIS